# Run script as root under Busybox?

Tags: linux, busybox

I have written a shell script that has to be run as root under Busybox. My first thought was to add the script to /etc/busybox.conf like this:

```
/sbin/my_script.sh = ssx root.root
```

But this only works with the Busybox apps. How can I allow the script to be run with root permissions when executed by a normal user?